# FCM background notifications work on chrome desktop but not on chrome android

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM to push notifications and I have the following service worker:

```
    if ('undefined' === typeof window) {
    importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.9.1/firebase-app.js');
    importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.9.1/firebase-messaging.js');

    // Initialize Firebase(I have removed properties values)
    var config = {
        apiKey: "",
        authDomain: "",
        databaseURL: "",
        projectId: "",
        storageBucket: "",
        messagingSenderId: ""
    };

    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    const messaging = firebase.messaging();

    messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
            console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);

            const notificationTitle = payload.data.title;
            const notificationOptions = {
                body: payload.data.body,
                icon: payload.data.icon
            };

            console.log(notificationOptions);

            self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {

                clients.openWindow(payload.data.link);
            });

            return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
                notificationOptions);

    });
}
```

The above code is working on chrome desktop but for chrome android, it's not working even Notifications permission is allowed.

I have debugged **setBackgroundMessageHandler** it is called but no notification is displayed and no error has occurred

**PS:**

My website is using Https